# Error when running to 'npm-start' on React app

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

I'm trying to run a React app, but when I try to start the development server, the
error appears.

[image]

Not quite sure why this happened, because I run it a week ago and was working fine. I tried reinstalling it, running 'reacts-scripts start', none of these worked.

Comment: did you move the project? it looks like you are inside a folder on your desktop, but it's trying to reference the package.json as if the project used to be initialized in your user folder...

Comment: i think so, theres a way to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure I've run into this specific issues before, but sometimes deleting your node_modules folder and re-running `npm install` can help...

Comment: maybe paste in your package.json here... maybe something weird in there

Comment: you have a package.json inside the current folder right? located at \Desktop\project\js-project\package.json ?